# Video streaming stops after a few frames using GStreamer and QGC

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I am attempting to stream RGB color video from my UAV on to QGC running on my ubuntu laptop using GStreamer.

My pipeline is built as

```
char str_pipeline[200];

snprintf(str_pipeline, sizeof( str_pipeline ), "appsrc name=mysource ! videoconvert ! "
"video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=NV12 ! vaapih264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay !"
"udpsink host=%s port=5600", "192.168.8.2");

pipeline = gst_parse_launch( str_pipeline, &error );

if( !pipeline )
{
printf( "gst_parse_launch error. Cannot launch GStreamer..: %s\n", error->message );
return;
}

appsrc = gst_bin_get_by_name( GST_BIN( pipeline ), "mysource" );

app_caps = gst_caps_new_simple( "video/x-raw", "format", G_TYPE_STRING, "RGB",
"width", G_TYPE_INT, WIDTH, "height", G_TYPE_INT, HEIGHT, NULL );

gst_app_src_set_caps( GST_APP_SRC( appsrc ), app_caps );
gst_caps_unref( app_caps );
g_object_set( G_OBJECT( appsrc ), "is-live", TRUE, "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL );
```

The video stops streaming on QGC (even thou frames are been sent to it) after a few frames.

I check the pipeline state after every send and for the first frame it is PAUSED and thereafter it is PLAYING.

Is there something in my pipeline that is wrong ? What is a correct pipeline to stream RGB COLOR video ? Am I missing some pipeline elements ?